# Divide object in array of arrays using keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following object :

```
{ a1: "Foo", b1: "Boo" , c1: "Coo", a2: "Doo" , b2: "Goo", c2: "Soo", ....... c50: "Zoo" }
```

I want to divide this in an array of arrays that will look like this :

```
[["Foo","Boo","Coo"], ["Doo","Goo","Soo"]......[ .., ..,"Zoo"]]
```

What is the best practice for doing that ?

Comment: How close did you get with your most recent attempt at accomplishing this? Any code you can share?

Comment: Gather the keys using `Object.keys()`, then loop over them and push the values to separate arrays based on the number part of given key name.

Comment: That is not a JSON object. That is a JavaScript object literal. The terms are not interchangeable.

Comment: "Consider the following json" - you don't have JSON there, the keys need to be wrapped in double-quotes.

Comment: @mkaatman I haven't got close enough to share code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use `reduce()` on `Object.keys()` to return one object and then `map()` keys of that object to return values which will be array of values.

```js
var obj = { a1: "Foo", b1: "Boo" , c1: "Coo", a2: "Doo" , b2:"Goo", c2:"Soo", c50:"Zoo"}

var o = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
 var newKey = e.match(/\d+/)[0]
 r[newKey] = (r[newKey] || []).concat(obj[e])
 return r
}, {})

var result = Object.keys(o).map(e => o[e])

console.log(result)
```

With ES-7 you could use `Object.values()` but it still has bad browser support, but the solution looks like this.

```js
var obj = { a1: "Foo", b1: "Boo" , c1: "Coo", a2: "Doo" , b2:"Goo", c2:"Soo", c50:"Zoo"}

var result = Object.values(Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
 var newKey = e.match(/\d+/)[0]
 return r[newKey] = (r[newKey] || []).concat(obj[e]), r
}, {}))


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the keys with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), iterate with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over them, get the numerical part with [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), decrement it for the index and push the value.

```js
var object = { a1: "Foo", b1: "Boo" , c1: "Coo", a2: "Doo" , b2:"Goo", c2:"Soo", c50:"Zoo"},
    result = [];
    
Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
    var i = key.match(/\d+$/) - 1;
    result[i] = result[i] || [];
    result[i].push(object[key]);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Don't think this works as intended, if you switch places of `a1` and `b2`, the results will be `["Boo", "Foo", "Coo"]` for the first array instead.

Comment: @Arg0n, as i understood the question, the number shows the index for the result set. if you switch `a1` and `b2`, you get different resuls.

Comment: As i interpret it, the letter represents the index in the array, and the number represents the index of the array.

Comment: i see the number as index indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var obj = { a1: "Foo", b1: "Boo" , c1: "Coo", a2: "Doo" , b2:"Goo", c2:"Soo" };
var indexObj = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 };
var result = [];

for(var prop in obj) {
   var index = indexObj[prop[0]];
   var array = prop.match(/\d+$/) - 1;

   if(!result[array]) {
      result[array] = [];
   }

   result[array][index] = obj[prop];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
//[["Foo","Boo","Coo"],["Doo","Goo","Soo"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do as follows;

```js
var obj = { a1: "Foo", b1: "Boo" , c1: "Coo", a2: "Doo" , b2: "Goo", c2: "Soo", a3: "Hello", b3: "to", c3: "you", c50: "Zoo" },
    res = Object.keys(obj)
                .reduce(function(r,c){
                          var t = /\d+/.exec(c)[0];
                          r.t = r.t !== t ? (r.push([obj[c]]), t)
                                          : (r[r.length-1].push(obj[c]), t);
                          return r;
                        },[]);
console.log(res);
```